# A signed GCS URL got 'SignatureDoesNotMatch'. the URL signed by a service with workload identity

Tags: identity, workload, google-cloud-storage

In a workload identity enabled GKE cluster, a service signed a GCS file but got: 'SignatureDoesNotMatch' after about 10 days.

Does the system-managed private key rotation cause it?

What should I do to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could review your expiration days assigned at your URL, in the following example is set to 3 days (`days signurl -d 3d`) also if you are using the flag `-u` in your command to generate the URL  you could try to remove it as a workaround